# Backbone router doesn't work with requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a backbone router that uses `require js`. Everything seems fine to me but it isnt working. I am calling `router` from my `app.js`:

**Router JS:**

```
define([
   'jquery',
   'underscore',
   'backbone',
   'view/questions/index'
], function($, _, Backbone, IndexView){
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '/': 'index'
    }
});

var initialize = function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter();

    // Index Route
    app_router.on('index', function(){
        var indexView = new IndexView();
        console.log('test');
        indexView.initialize();
    });

    // Default Route
    app_router.on('defaultAction', function(actions){
        console.log('No Route', actions);
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
};

return {
    initialize: initialize
};
});
```

**App JS:**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'router'
], function($, _, Backbone, Router){
var initialize = function(){
    Router.initialize();
};

return {
    initialize: initialize
};
});
```

Comment: Did this work without requirejs?  I've always personally used the events hash with the router, but looking at the source it seems that if you want to bind to events, they need to be prefixed with "route:", e.g. `on("route:index")`, not simply "index".  I'm not a Backbone expert by any means, perhaps other versions weren't like this.

Comment: Actually I got this working already. The problem was with `'/'` and has to be referred as `("route:index")`. Cheers Mate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guys I actually got this working. Here is the changes I made in the code.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'index'
    }
});
```

And Here:

```
app_router.on('route:index', function(){
    var indexView = new IndexView();
    console.log('test');
    indexView.initialize();
});
```